# RXJS conditionally call observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables, iif

```
  const observable$ = iif(() => this.shippingTabModified,
      //Shipping Tab Modified True
      of(this.updateShippingInfo())
        .pipe(),
      //IF Shipping Tab Not Modified    
      of(this.shippingInfoService.getShipmentInfoByCardIdObservable(this.data.CardId))
        .pipe()
    )

    observable$.subscribe();
```

From above code i want to achieve following scenario

```
if(foo === true)
{
  updatemethod()
}
// if foo is true and update method is executed we need to wait until update method is finished then go to second method

// If foo is false we can call second method without waiting
secondmethod();
```

But from rxjs code which i wrote above, it always go to update method it is not considering the value of `this.shippingTabModified`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage on the `concat` function and do something like this

```
const observables$ = condition ? [obs$1, obs$2] : [obs$2];

concat(...observables$).subscribe();
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use

```js
const obs$ = this.shippingTabModified ? 
  of(this.updateShippingInfo()) : 
  this.shippingInfoService.getShipmentInfoByCardIdObservable(this.data.CardId);

obs$.subscribe();
```

**EDIT**

Calling on condition :

```js
const obs$ = of(this.updateShippingInfo()).pipe(
  switchMap(res => this.shippingTabModified ?
    of(res) :
    this
      .shippingInfoService
      .getShipmentInfoByCardIdObservable(this.data.CardId)
)
```

Comment: if shippingTabModified === true i need to call both updateshippinginfo and getshipment method sequentially

Comment: @Thushara ok did not get it from your code, please see edited answer